# Unable to run Maplestory

Tags: maplestory

My computer specs are as follows:

- Processor: i5-3570k,
- Motherboard: P8Z77-v-pro,
- Memory: 16gb DDR3,
- Hard disk: Seagate Barracuda 2TB,
- Graphics card: GTX670,
- Windows 7 Professional

I have tried logging into the maplestory website (global), however, after downloading the installer and installing pando media booster, the download does not start at all. So, I downloaded through the workaround files [here](http://maplestory.nexon.net/news/news/current/00FwK). I followed the instructions (added to same folder, ran the appropriate file) and successfully installed the game. However, I encounter the following errors when I try to run the game:

1) Running through Chrome: *Error code 11004*, Maplestory not run at all.

2) Running through internet explorer: Can select server, when I choose a channel, instantly crashes with no error messages.

3) Running through gamelauncher.exe: I see the in-client log in window, and enter my email/pw. However, clicking the login button does nothing, and after the while, the game crashes with the message 'you have been disconnected from the login server'.*

**Extra information:**

1) I am running a dual-monitor set up. I have had some problems running other games in the past because of this reason.

2) I am using a university internet connection. Some websites do not load, others are slow (throttled). I am not well-versed in internet literature, but if I had to guess, the problem lies somewhere here.

Any help resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your note #2 is likely the problem: your university network is blocking/filtering a network port it happens to need or is classifying the traffic as "malicious" or "greedy" and throttling it so hard that it dies. A proxy service like TunnelBear might help, but I can only guess.

Answer (score 2):

Use the GameLauncher.exe in the MapleStory folder.